# Map retorna una coma inesperada

Tags: javascript, structured-data

Quiero generar structured data para SEO, para ello tengo una función:

```js
return `
    {
      "@context": "http://schema.org",
      "@type": "BreadcrumbList",
      "itemListElement": [
        {
          "@type": "ListItem",
          "position": 1,
          "item": {
            "@type": "Thing",
            "@id":  "${baseURL}",
            "name": "Home",
            "image": ""
          }
        },    
        ${segments.map((segment, index) => {
          const url = index === 0 ? `${baseURL}/${segment}` : `${baseURL}/${segments.slice(0, 1 + index).join("/")}`;
          let returnThis;

          if (segment !== "units") {
             returnThis = ` {
                    "@type": "ListItem",
                    "position": ${index + 2},
                    "item": {
                      "@type": "Thing",
                      "@id": "${url}",
                      "name": "${capitalizeEachWord(segment.toLowerCase().replace(/-/g, " "))}",
                      "image": ""}}`;
          }
                
          position++;
          return returnThis;
        }).join("")}
      ]
    }
```

Como pueden ver hay una condicion `if (segment !== "units")` porque quiero saltearme el breadcrumb `www.misitio.com/slug-1/units` debido a que no existe tal pagina.

La cuestion es que logro filtrar el elemento que no necesito dentro del `map`, pero a la hora de retornar el resultado, aparecen dos comas juntas en lugar de una, algo asi:

```
[
  {id: 1},
  {id: 2},,
  {id: 4}     
]
```

En una respues de SO encontré que podia arreglar esto agregando `.join('')` al finalizar el `map` pero el resultado ahora tiene otro error, no hay ninguna coma:

```
[
  {id: 1},
  {id: 2}
  {id: 4}     
]
```

Alguien sabe como solucionar esto?

Comment: Lo que hice de momento es: en lugar de agregar ``.join('')``, agregué ``.toString().replaceAll(",,", ",")`` pero no sé si es una buena forma de solucionarlo.

Comment: Está raro que el contenido de returnThis esté entre carácteres backtick ( ` ).

Comment: @Alfabravo si lo hago sin backtiks dentro del objeto final obtengo el primer elemento, que esta bien, y a partir de ahi: ``[object Object],,[object Object] `` no solo recibe mal los datos sino que ademas las dos comas siguen ahi.

Comment: ¿En `${index + 2}` no te faltan las comillas? `"position": "${index + 2}"`

Comment: @FranciscoJavier gracias, no habia visto ese detalle. De todas maneras el problema persiste

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error que tienes proviene de un mal entendimiento de la función `map`, esta función NO reemplaza un `for` ni funciona exactamente igual a él. Un `map` transforma una lista en otra lista con una relación 1 a 1, es decir si tienes 10 elementos en la primera, tendrás los mismo 10 en la de salida.

Aquí un ejemplo simplificado de tu problema.

Digamos que tenemos una `lista` y queremos transformar los `1` en `a` y filtrar los `0`

```js
const lista = [1,1,1,0,1];

const otraLista = lista.map(a=>{ 
   let returnThis;
   if(a!=0){
      returnThis = "a";
   }
   return returnThis;

});
console.log(otraLista);
console.log(otraLista.toString());
```

Como puedes ver retorna una lista con la misma cantidad de elementos, pero en la posición del `0` retorna `undefined`, y al mostrarlo como `string` como lo estás haciendo tú, `undefined` queda en blanco mostrando 2 comas

**La solución:**

Lo más simple es filtar antes del `map`

```js
const lista = [1,1,1,0,1];

const otraLista = lista.filter(a=>a==1).map(a=>{ 
   let returnThis;
   if(a!=0){
      returnThis = "a";
   }
   return returnThis;

});
console.log(otraLista);
console.log(otraLista.toString());
```

En tu caso

```
${segments.filter(segment => segment !== "units").map((segment, index) => {
//ETC...
// obviamente esto == > if (segment !== "units")  ya no lo necesitas, porque los elementos están filtrados
```

O si quieres puedes crear tu propia función, que haga un `map+filter` así no iteras 2 veces:

```js
Array.prototype.mapFilter = function(condicion,fn){
  let i =0;
  const result = [];
  for(let item of this){
    if(condicion(item)){
      result.push(fn(item,i));
      i++;
    }
    
  }
  return result;
}
//==========================================================

const lista = [1,1,1,0,1];
const otraLista = lista.mapFilter( a=> a!=0 , a=>{ 
   let returnThis = "a";
   return returnThis;

});
console.log(otraLista);
console.log(otraLista.toString());
```

Comment: 5 palabras: crack